# Unix script to input file1 file2...etc and output file1out file2out...etc?

Tags: java, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a script that runs multiple input files through a .jar and sends their output to similarly-named output files.

To better explain, I have a jar file, let's call it HelloWorld.jar.

I also have input files file1, file2, and file3.

I need output files file1out, file2out, file3out.

Right now my script is just

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar < file1 > file1out
java -jar HelloWorld.jar < file2 > file2out
etc
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Something like...

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar < * > (not really sure for this part)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which shell you are using, you could try a for loop.  This should work in sh, bash, zsh; but probably not csh, ksh.

```
for f in *
do
  java -jar HelloWorld.jar < $f > ${f}.out
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few  things

1. Write a unix for loop in shell script to loop through the files and create an output to a file. The name of the output file will be inputfile + "fileout".

`

```
 for file in /path/to/file1.txt /path/to/file2.txt /path/to/file3.txt
    do            
        java -jar HelloWorld.jar < file1 > $programmatic_file_name
    done
```

`
2. You can parameterize your java application to accept a list of files as input(String args[]) and create the same logic as #1 in the file . I would rather recommend  #2

1. You can even make your java application read all the files in a directory and create all the output files in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..9}
  java -jar HelloWorld.jar < file${i} > file${i}out
```